# Git doesn't change working directory

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm using Windows 10. Before I install `git 2.6.1.windows.1`, I have installed `git 1.9.5.github.0` (by installing GitHub Desktop), it works just fine.
But when I installed `git 2.6.1.windows.1` (from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com)), I'm not able to use git anymore:

- The powershell console displayed `[(unknown)]` instead of `[master]`, even when I changed working directory to my project, it still display `[(unknown)]`
- When I `git add` (or `git commit`, `git push`), It told me an error: `fatal: Not a git repository: 'C:\Program Files\Git'`

After that, I returned to the old version of git - `git 1.9.5.github.0`, but the fault still there.

I think git didn't change its working directory, I have no idea.
Now, I'm not able to work with git.

How to fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

Again, this is *not the first time* I use git, I never forget `cd myproject`. However, although I moved to the project, git "thought" itself working in `C:\Program Files\Git` and doesn't "realize" that the working directory has been changed! That's the problem, As the title: **Git doesn't change working directory**

**EDIT 2:**

When `Get-Command git` in powershell, it returns:

```
CommandType      Name         Version      Source
-----------      ----         -------      ------
Application      git.exe      2.6.0.0      C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

**EDIT 3:**

@EdwardThomson asked me for output of `git config --list` and `Get-ChildItem Env:`

- Output of `git config --list`: http://pastebin.com/qUxKnBiT
- Output of `Get-ChildItem Env:` http://pastebin.com/ShPcypF0

**SOLVED:**

I have received an email which mentions `GIT_DIR`, then I know what exactly caused my problem! It's because of **environment variable `GIT_DIR`**, I set `GIT_DIR` to the folder which contains `git` for convenience **without aware that `git` uses it**

Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: I did experience this kind of issue on my box. Try selecting the branch explicitly using 'git checkout <branch-name>' e.g 'git checkout master'

Comment: @BalajiKatika It doesn't deal my issue. `fatal: Not a git repository: 'C:\Program Files\Git'` still there.

Comment: have you tried **git init**??

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma I tried `git init`, git said `C:/Program Files/Git/refs: Permission denied`, I also checked `C:\Program Files\Git\refs`, `refs` folder doesn't exist in `Git`, what's `refs` (file or dir)?, and what to do next?

Comment: In command line/CLI, you will get this error if your current directory is NOT the repository. So, you have to first CD into the repo.

Comment: also check your git configuration by : **git config -l**

Comment: What does `Get-Command git` return in PowerShell?

Comment: @jeremytwfortune CommandType: Application; Name: git.exe; Version: 2.6.0.0; Source: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe.

Comment: I found [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12353), which seems to indicate that perhaps there's a problem with the pathing. It's in the context of another product, but it's worth trying. Can you try to reinstall 2.6 to a path without spaces, like `C:\git`?

Comment: Also, can you see if `core.worktree` is set in either the global or system `.gitconfig`. Or either of the `GIT_COMMON_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE` variables are set. Take a look at the `core.worktree` section in [scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `git` work correctly if you use it from `cmd.exe`?  What about "git bash"?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I also tried with `cmd`, `bash` (in both cygwin and git bash), all them give the same error!

Comment: Can you paste the output of `git config --list` and `Get-ChildItem Env:`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson ok, I pasted, see the question!

Answer (score -1):

you must be inside a folder having .git directory (hidden).

Comment: The project is cloned, `.git` folder always been there. The problem is not `.git` folder, it's git still "work" with `C:\Program Files\Git` yet I have `cd myproject`. I had told the error message in my question.